# Web services error I found the error in web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

These method in AutoComplete.asmx

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> GetCountries(string prefixText)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
             "MarinaNewConnectionString"].ToString());

     con.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
         "select * from Marina where Country like @Name+'%'", con);

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     da.Fill(dt);

     List<string> CountryNames = new List<string>();

     for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
     {
         CountryNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][5].ToString());
     }

     return CountryNames;
}
```

I found the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. --->
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type

EDIT:

The SQL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Marina]( 
    [SNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [WebSource] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [MarinaName] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [Region] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [Address] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [Country] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [fax] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [Phone] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [Email] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [Website] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [latitude] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [langitude] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [NumberOfMoorings] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [MGiD] [varchar](500) NULL, 
    [Association] [varchar](200) NULL,
) ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The StackTrace:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object
>   of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type
>   'System.String[]'. at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write3_Arr‌​ayOfString(Object
>   o) at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfStringSerializer1.Serialize(‌​Object
>   objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: This is my table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Marina](
 [SNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [WebSource] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [MarinaName] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Region] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Address] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Country] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [fax] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Phone] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Email] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Website] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [latitude] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [langitude] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [NumberOfMoorings] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [MGiD] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Association] [varchar](200) NULL,
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write3_ArrayOfString(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfStringSerializer1.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Can you run it in debug mode?

Comment: In this code no line show error

Comment: error occurs after in browser

Comment: everything looks fine ... pls run by adding some dummy data without db connection and try ...CountryNames.Add("Piush");CountryNames.Add("shukla");

Comment: Try making the change as suggested by soniiic. The old asmx doesnt support return of list objects. Convert them to an array and return it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't be able to return a `List<string>` object.  Return a string array rather than a generic.

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetCountries(string prefixText)
{
     // .....

     return CountryNames.ToArray();
}
```